# Templating languages and how to restrict access to Namespaces in Razor template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, razor, templating

**Background**

I have a web service that returns entity objects with a dynamic list of fields.  Currently the web service can return the entities, but I want to make it simpler, and allow the client to provide a template string that I parse using the entity and then return the result.

Here is an example:

```
var entity = new Entity();
entity.Fields.Add("status", "worked");
var template = "My template parser {{status}}!";
var result = service.ParseTemplate(template, entity);
// Expected result is "My template parser worked!"
```

This much I can do using a simple regex.  I then decided I needed some basic logic, such as for loops and if statements.  I decided to use [Cottle](http://r3c.github.io/Cottle/), which is a great open source templating engine.  Unfortunately this isn't going to cut it as my entity grows more complex.  Here is the kind of thing I want to do:

```
var entity = new Entity();
entity.Fields.Add("name", "Bob");

var entity2 = new Entity();
entity2.Fields.Add("status", "worked");
entity2.Fields.Add("person", entity);

var template = "My name is {{person.name}}.  My template parser {{status}}!";
var result = service.ParseTemplate(template, entity2);
// Expected result is "My name is Bob.  My template parser worked!"
```

As you can see, this second example allows a dot based syntax to find the attached entity and read its fields as well.

**Now onto the meat of the question...**

I decided that Razor can accomplish what I am looking for using the [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) project.  However I am hesitant to invite people to send me a template filled with server side code for obvious reasons.  Is there a way that I can parse the template while removing access to the entire .Net library?

**Alternative question**

Is there a better templating solution out there that anyone can recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using XSLT in the end, as it is robust, secure and building an XML document to parse is far simpler and more flexible than previous approaches.